# Neo4j Upgradation from 2.1 to 2.3

Tags: neo4j

The following points are taken from the [Up gradation Link](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-upgrading.html#explicit-upgrade)
`1. Cleanly shut down the older version of Neo4j, if it is running.
2. Install Neo4j 2.1.5, and set it up to use the same database store directory (typically data/graph.db).
3. Set the Neo4j configuration parameter allow_store_upgrade=true in your conf/neo4j.properties file. Neo4j will fail to start without this configuration set.
4. Start up Neo4j.
5. The database store upgrade will occur during startup.
6. The allow_store_upgrade configuration parameter should be removed, set to false or commented out.
7. Information about the upgrade and a progress indicator are logged into the messages.log file, inside the database store directory.`

The sixth point, After starting the higher version of neo4j, should we again set `allow_store_upgrade=false`. 
 I have followed the same steps, but the older database which was 10gb after upgrading to new version, database size is only 1.7gb. 
I am worried, all my relations that are imported in older version can be seen in newer version?
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You're mentioning "from 2.1 to 2.3". Please note that as of today there's just a milestone build from 2.3 M01 available. Upgrading a database from a milestone version is not guaranteed, see release notes.

Aside from your graph data itself the `graph.db` directory contains (depending on your config) transaction logs. These might be a large fraction of the complete directory.

To be sure that your datastore is consistent, use the consistency checker, see http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Now i am trying top upgrade it to 2.2. 
I am confused with the sixth point mentioned in my previous post. Do i have to set `allow_store_upgrade` to false after starting the newer version?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should complete step #6 *after* you have successfully started up the new version once (which is what triggers the upgrade). Perhaps a slightly more detailed process could be written as:

```
4. Start up Neo4j.
5. The database store upgrade will occur during startup.
6. Review information about the upgrade contained in the messages.log file, inside the database store directory.
7. After a successful upgrade:
  7a. Shut down Neo4j
  7b. Remove, comment out or set to false the allow_store_upgrade configuration parameter.
  7c. Start up Neo4j.
```

Comment: After setting `allow_store_upgrade=true` and starting the neo4j, My database was not successfully upgraded.  Expected database was 10GB, it is showing only 1.7GB after upgradation.  So how to restore it fully

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you mean, but there's no magic way to reverse the process. Restoring your database after a failed upgrade would normally involve restoring the database files that you should have backed up beforehand, and reinstalling/using the earlier version of the Neo4j software. Have you actually tested your data set to find out if you've lost something, rather than simply relying on the external file size? Even a simple node and relationship count should give you some idea - you might be concerned about nothing.

Comment: I have made a backup of older version of neo4j. The older database path was given to higher version of neo4j and started it. But the statistics shown in webadmin page of neo4j are totally different after starting it. In higher version, less number of nodes are shown than previous version

Comment: So your problem is a failing upgrade, and no longer a question about how to upgrade. I think this answers your original question and you should accept it and open a new one to address your actual problem.